# Duda con fomularios, objetos y arrays en PHP

Tags: php, poo

Estoy aprendiendo POO en PHP y en un ejercicio a la hora de enviar datos de formularios a los objetos e ingresar los objetos en un array quede en blanco. Estuve recorriendo mucho por tutoriales de yt, foros, etc pero no pude encontrar o entender mucho. Todo el código tiene que ser hecho solo con HTML y PHP. Paso a explicarlo porque es medio largo, desde ya gracias por leer.

El ejercicio me pide primero una clase para administrar los productos de un supermercado cuyos atributos son: la clave numérica, la  descripción, el precio y el stock. También me pide como métodos que defina a un constructor con parámetros.

```
<?php
class Producto{

private $clave;
private $descripcion;
private $precio;
private $stock;

public function __construct($clave, $descripcion, $precio, $stock){
    $this->clave = $clave;
    $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
    $this->precio = $precio;
    $this->stock = $stock;
}
public function setClave($clave){
    $this->clave = $clave;
}
public function getClave(){
    return $this->clave;
}
public function setDescripcion($descripcion){
    $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
}
public function getDescipcion(){
    return $this->descripcion;
}
public function setPrecio($precio){
    $this->precio = $precio;
}
public function getPrecio(){
    return $this->precio;
}
public function setStock($stock){
    $this->stock = $stock;
}
public function getStock(){
    return $this->stock;
}
```

}
?>

Luego me pide que use a esa clase para declarar un arreglo de objetos y controlar un inventario de hasta 50 productos utilizando el method POST. Y ademas este programa debe tener un menú con los siguientes items: Alta de producto, Baja de producto, Listado de producto, Ordenar producto por número de clave y Salir.

Antes de mostrar el código les cuento el problema y es que no puedo hacer que varios objetos entren al array para poder imprimirlos. Tampoco estoy muy seguro de como dar de baja pero paso a paso.

Aqui esta el html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Inventario de 50 productos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
      <label for="clave">Ingrese la clave del producto</label></br>
      <input type="number" name="clave" id="clave" required></br>

      <label for="descripcion">Ingrese la descripción del producto</label></br>
      <input type="text" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" required></br>

      <label for="precio">Ingrese precio del producto</label></br>
      <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" required></br>

      <label for="stock">Ingrese el stock del producto</label></br>
      <input type="number" name="stock" id="stock" required></br>

      <button type="submit" name="alta" id="alta">Dar de alta</button>
      <button type="submit" name="baja" id="baja">Dar de baja</button>
      <button type="submit" name="listado" id="listado">Mostar listado</button>
      <button type="submit" name="ordenar" id="ordenar">Ordenar por clave</button>
      <button type="submit" name="salir" id="salir">Salir</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí esta el php que es donde tengo la duda básicamente. El print_r solo muestra el objeto que metí en ese momento y no los anteriores. El SESSION lo usó porque es la única manera que encontre de que los datos no se borren en otros ejercicios anteriores. Creí que poniendo $_SESSION["art"][]= $oproducto; se iba solucionar el tema de guardarlos pero me tira error. También intente con foreachs pero no imprimia nada o me tiraba error. Desde ya lamento que sea tan largo y gracias por leer hasta acá.

```
if (strlen(session_id()) < 1) {
session_start();}

 include_once("producto1.php");

 if(isset($_POST["alta"])){
   $_SESSION["cantidad"] = $_SESSION["cantidad"] +1;
   $cantidad = $_SESSION["cantidad"];
   if($cantidad<=50){
       $oproducto = new Producto($_POST["clave"], $_POST["descripcion"], $_POST["precio"], 
       $_POST["stock"]);
       $oproducto->setClave($_POST["clave"]);
       $oproducto->setDescripcion($_POST["descripcion"]);
       $oproducto->setPrecio($_POST["precio"]);
       $oproducto->setStock($_POST["stock"]);
       $_SESSION["art"]= $oproducto;
       print_r($_SESSION["art"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Si piensas ir guardando los objetos dentro de la clave  `art`  de tu variable de sesión, tienes que ponerlo así: `$_SESSION["art"][]= $oproducto;`  eso hará que cada vez se cree un nuevo índice con el nuevo objeto, debido a los `[]`, sin eso, estarías cada vez reemplazando el valor de `art` sin más. Por otra parte, los *setter* son redundantes, porque estás pasando los valores a través del constructor, cuando creas la instancia del objeto. Con eso es suficiente, no tienes necesidad de usar los *setter* para este caso.

Answer (score 0):

Crea la clase antes de iniciar la sesión, o sea,

```
include_once("producto1.php");  //aquí es donde creas la clase
if (strlen(session_id()) < 1) {
session_start();}
```

Luego podrás guardar los objetos como dices en tu ejemplo $_SESSION[art][] = $oproducto.

Comment: ¿Qué diferencia hace incluir antes de iniciar sesión?

Comment: Respuesta corta: que así funciona ;).   En serio y muy resumido,  lo que pasa es que cuando inicias la sesión php ya conoce esa clase definida y "entiende" sus objetos, con lo lo puede serializar para almacenarlo en $_SESSION.